# R find the index of the maximum value across columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, max

Given a dataframe in R, how can you find the **index** of the maximum value across multiple columns (excluding NAs) and also the column name of the index of the maximum value across the columns.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `which.max` with `apply` to get the column number where you find the first max. This can be used in `colnames` to get the name of this column.

```
x$indexOfMax <- apply(x, 1, which.max)
x$colName <- colnames(x)[x$indexOfMax]
x
#  Red Blue Yellow Green Purple indexOfMax colName
#1   5    8     10     3     NA          3  Yellow
#2   3    7      2    NA      1          2    Blue
#3   3   NA     NA     2      8          5  Purple
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(Red=c(5,3,3), Blue=c(8,7,NA), Yellow=c(10,2,NA)
 , Green=c(3,NA,2), Purple=c(NA,1,8))
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works well. However, when trying it on a larger dataset there are some instances where all columns contain NA values. Then the indexOfMax column changes to a different format e.g. integer(0) or c(Purple = 5) rather than just 5. Is there a workaround for when all are NAs?

Comment: When there are only `NA` you usually can not say where the largest number is. Can you make an update of your question which shows the problem?